# Crystal report does not show design and tools

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm using VS 2010 and i installed Crystal report runtime 13_0_1. When i create a new rpt it does not show the design and tools its shows some codes.  LIke this

[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/hs6rk3.png]

Please advice me on this.

Comment: i think it shows only hexadecimal codes

Comment: May be crystal report tool is not installed. Try to start/open the Visual studio with admin privileges on Win7

Comment: i installed CRforVS_13_0_2.exe. is it the cystal report report

Comment: Yes! it is. http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp

Comment: i already installed it. then whats the problem :(. please help

Answer (score 0):

Install crystal report 2007 or locate folder from where you installed visual studio and search for crystal report setup file.
this should solve your problem.
all the best.

Comment: Why you are thanx for yourself?